# Cannot build C++ Static Library (Windows Phone 8.1) in ARM mode in VS2015

Tags: c++, msbuild, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Pro RTM after an upgrade from 2015 RC.

When I create a new C++ Static Library (Windows Phone 8.1) (File | New Project | Visual C++ | Windows | Windows 8 | Windows Phone | Static Library (Windows Phone 8.1), it builds fine in X86. When I try to build it in ARM, I get

```
Error   D8027   cannot execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_arm\c2.dll'
```

Which is strange because it references 12.0 (VS2013) and VS2015 is 14.0. Any ideas how to solve it? I installed VS2015 with C++ support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
What worked for me was to run the 'Repair' option in the VS installer from the control panel 'Programs and Features'. It took a while, but after the reboot I was able to rebuild without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some stale components in your installation (left over from RC).  In VS 2015 RC, there was a bug where project templates were installed even if the required tools were not.  This was fixed in the RTM release.

For Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 support, you need to select the "Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools" optional feature in VS setup.  That will include the compiler, libs, and SDKs needed to work with components for those app platforms.

Context: For Store & Phone apps (8/8.1), the VC++ compiler toolset and app platform are directly linked.  So, the fact that Windows Phone 8.1 projects are attempting to make use of the VS 2013 compiler is expected.

Windows Phone 8.0 => v110 VC++ compiler toolset;
Windows Phone 8.1 & Windows 8.1 (store) => v120 VC++ compiler toolset

Comment: I have Windows (Phone) 8.1 tools installed, C# phone projects work fine.

Comment: If 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_arm\c2.dll' is missing, I'd suggest attempting to repair your Visual Studio 2015 RTM installation.  The other thing that comes to mind is that if you have Visual Studio 2012 installed on the machine, be sure to install VS 2012 Update 4, as well.

Comment: VS 12.0 is Visual Studio 2013 not 2012 .. The c2.dll exists at the path,